# Multiple DataTable columns stacked horizontally in one GridView Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, datatable

How can `multiple columns` from a `DataTable` be stacked into one column of a GridView ?

Is there a better asp control for performing such an operation?

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you are binding that value to a label, then it will simply be:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the columns and rows on the server, pushing the items into any control that will display this one column (list, one column HTML table etc.)